# Snowflake active directory accountadmin

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do I grant accountadmin role to a created role in active directory group ?

error that I get:

grant role accountadmin to role adaccountadmin

*Circular role grants not allowed. Granting role ACCOUNTADMIN to adaccountadmin would create a cycle.*

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake you grant a role to its parent role, not the other way round. see [Snowflake Roles Syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-role.html#syntax)

ACCOUNTADMIN is a top level role in Snowflake so you cant make it the child of another role

Comment: OP did not attempt to assign ACCOUNTADMIN role to another role... they tried to assign it to itself (self-reference). Also, it *IS* technically possible to grant the ACCOUNTADMIN role to another role (such as a custom role)... but it is a VERY BAD PRACTICE.

Comment: Not a problem if I have misunderstood this but in the original question they appear to be assigning one role to another, not assigning a role to itself: grant role accountadmin to role adaccountadmin

Comment: My mistake. So the self-reference was a red herring. But it is possible to assign ACCOUNTADMIN to any other role. There MUST be a circular role assignment in the original post.